# Exibir Rótulos De Dados Em Gráfico De Colunas No R (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, barplot

Sou iniciante em R e estou tentando criar um gráfico de barras e não consigo exibir os rótulos dos dados em cada barra.

Segue link do data frame utilizado:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P6RLgzOgnZisI4BUYFHsEZ3b-Ca4XXd-uEg7t-_vASI

Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)

Vendas <- read_excel("D:/BDados.xlsx", sheet = "Plan1")

ggplot(Vendas)+
  stat_count(aes(ID_LOC)) +
  labs(title = "Vendas", x="ID_Regioes", y="Total") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 10)
```

Meu gráfico esta ficando assim:

[image: Gráfico]

Comment: Qual das colunas é que é o rótulo? E quer que esteja onde, em coma das colunas?

Comment: Creio que o AP chama de rótulo o valor numérico correspondente à altura das barras. Ou seja, ele deseja que, acima da coluna A, apareça um número aproximadamente igual a 375; acima da coluna B, quase 1200, e assim por diante.

Comment: Isso mesmo! Preciso que apareça os rótulos de dados de todas as colunas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta solução usa o pacote `dplyr` para fazer o pré-processamento dos dados.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Vendas %>%
  group_by(ID_LOC) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ID_LOC, n, label = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(y = n), vjust = -0.1) +
  labs(title = "Vendas", x = "ID_Regioes", y = "Total") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 10)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar tando o `geom_text()`qunato `geom_label()`. Veja o exemplo usando o `geom_text()`. 
Primeiro vou ciar uma dataframe para usar como exemplo.

```
library(ggplot2)
vendas = data.frame(total =c(1150, 900, 850, 530, 600),
                    ID_Regioes = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))

vendas %>% ggplot(aes(x = ID_Regioes, y = total)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1300))+
  geom_text(aes(label = total), 
            vjust = -1) +
  labs(title = "Vendas", x="ID_Regioes", y="total") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 10)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizei `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1300))` para ajustar os limites do eixo Y. Teste também como `geom_label()` para ver a diferença. 
Espero ter ajudado.